# How to set delimiter as "\\p{Punct}" excluding quotation mark?

Tags: java, parsing, java.util.scanner, delimiter

If I want to set the scanner's delimiter to `scanner.useDelimiter("\\p{Punct}");` but don't want the quotation mark to be included in that list, is there a simple way to exclude that?

I tried to do `s.useDelimiter("(\\p{Digit}|\\s|\\p{Punct}&&[^"])+");` but the quotation mark that is in the bracket is closing the for quotation mark.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can call the method [`Scanner#useDelimiter(Pattern)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#useDelimiter(java.util.regex.Pattern)):

```
scanner.useDelimiter(Pattern.compile("[\\p{Punct}&&[^\"]]"))
```

`[[\\p{Punct}&&[^\"]]` matches all characters covered by `\\p{Punct}` except the double quote which has been escaped.

Comment: I want the double quotes to be excluded ("), not the single quotes('), but the compiler is thinking it is a closing quotation and giving me an error.

Comment: @btrballin You need to escape it with a backslash.

Comment: Ok one last thing. Previously I used a `|` as a separator for different delimiters but you used `&&` for this particular one. I'm trying to implement whitespace also. How doe that go with the `&&` syntax?

Comment: Update: I experimented and `s.useDelimiter(Pattern.compile("[\\s|\\p{Punct}&&[^\"]]"));` includes the whitespace. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

This is called [Character Class Subtraction](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclasssubtract.html), see [Java Trail: [Regular Expression] Character Classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/char_classes.html):

> Finally, you can *use subtraction to negate one or more nested character classes*, such as [0-9&&[^345]]. This example creates a single character class that matches everything from 0 to 9, except the numbers 3, 4, and 5.

For the given request this is the pattern `[\p{Punct}&&[^"]]` (escape for a string literal, as normal).